# Cut the end of screws that are hitting a pocket door

Tags: screws

During a remodeling of a bathroom the drywall installer used screws that went about 1/4 inch into a space for a pocket door. Once reinstalled the pocket door hits the screws and needless to say it didn't go well.

The question is how to cut off the end of these screws since the tops are covered by drywall and then marble tile. Hate to undo the tile installation if there's another way of addressing this issue.

[image]

Comment: There are some good answers below so I won't chime in except to mention that any grinding or cutting operation can create sparks, and sparks can ignite dust in the pocket and start a fire. Sawdust remaining from construction can burn or smolder. Fluffy house dust is mostly hair and human skin cells, and that burns too. Before you create any sparks, be sure to have a working fire extinguisher or garden hose nearby. Monitor the pocket for a couple of hours after you finish and make sure you don't smell smoke. ***I'm not saying don't do it***, I'm just saying you should take precautions.

Comment: Unless I'm really confused it seems the heart of the question is how to cut the tips off of the screws inside the pocket door opening.  These aren't easily accessible screws.

Comment: @crip, you won't get a hacksaw blade to ride on those tips without some local stability. I'm not sure how you suggest that be done.  Also, power tools won't fit in there. Comment-answer flagged for deletion.

Comment: In case anyone else was confused, a [pocket door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_door) is a sliding door that disappears into an adjacent compartment when fully open.

Comment: What kind of access do you have there?  I can't tell what POV I'm looking at -- is that the top of the door?

Answer (score 12):

A grinding device of some sort will work more effectively and do less damage than a cutting device. One can use, as mentioned in the comments, a right angle grinder, but a hobby grinder such as Dremel™ manufactures will also work with the large diameter abrasive fiber disks. You don't have so much material to remove that it becomes burdensome and the hobby grinders will create less surface damage in the process. Source: direct experience.

Comment: An angle grinder would be ideal. However, it would probably be _very_ difficult to get it into a pocket-door sized opening. Therefore the hobby grinder would be the way to go. I'd use a grind stone, not a cutoff disk because of the angle involved - you can use the side (long axis) of the grind stone, while you have to use the edge (short axis) of the cutoff blade. Also, if you manage to grind away a little extra wood, it will _not_ be the end of the world.

Comment: How are you going to get even a dremel in there though?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, based on the lumber in the image, one could guess that the strips are 3/4" thick (one-by standard dimension) and there may be room for four, that's three inches. My Dremel™ is slightly smaller than 2" diameter. There are inexpensive HF models that are smaller. There might be enough wiggle room to make it work.

Comment: A pocket door slab is 1-3/8" thick. If the finish jambs are present, the gap will be no more than about 2". If they're not, _maybe_ 2-1/2". That might be enough.

Comment: Pretty tight quarters. Time to get out the long file.

Comment: Dremel does have a flex extender.. but I'm skeptical it would fit in there, and you'd still need to probably attach a rigid stick to it.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor As rrauenza said, Dremel has a flexible shaft attachment which should fit in the pictured space. The flexible shaft attachment even comes standard in some Dremel box sets. It should be moderately easy to use some duct tape to tape it to an appropriately sized metal or wood shaft which allows it to be pushed in there and sufficiently controlled. Either a grinding bit or a cutoff wheel would work. Given the space shown, I'd probably choose a cut-off wheel, as it will extend farther from the shaft, but a grinding bit may be better for the opposite reason, depending on the space.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use either a reciprocating saw with a metal cutting blade, you can get 12" long blades, or an oscillating tool.

isherwood is right, I tried on my pocket door even my M12 recip can't get in there.

I think you could get in there with a recip and 22" [extend-a-blade](https://www.prweb.com/releases/2005/01/prweb193908.htm) plus a 12" blade would get you in up to 34"

Comment: The oscillator is the way to go. Can use accurately with one hand and will fit in the hole.

Comment: A recipro saw will have trouble cutting hardened screws to begin with, and it'll be nearly impossible to keep the blade on those tapered tips. Also, both tools are large and a 12" blade won't reach.

Answer (score 2):

I would not think it very practical to get anything like a Dremel or oscillating power tool in the pocket door opening and then to work it with your arm in there.

If that's the case, you might try using 2 sided tape to attach some very coarse sandpaper to the door along where it's hitting the screws then just open and close the door while putting some pressure on the door in the direction of the screws.  You can put layers of extra tape if the sandpaper should protrude towards the screws more.

Comment: Interesting idea, but this won't remove enough material to be sure the new door won't be damaged at some point. Wood moves with the seasons, and hardware gets loose.

Comment: @isherwood yeah it might be a crappy idea except if nothing else works because of the tight space.  I feel like if OP's arm and Dremel would fit that that idea is obvious but it looks like OP isn't participating to know more.

Comment: "Isn't participating anymore" well, it's been less than 24 hours since the question was asked, and not _everyone_ lives on [diy.se]... Some folks might only be able to check 1x per day. _Though experience says you're probably right. :(_

Comment: A long piece of wood with coarse sandpaper glued on it might work also and not risk damage to the door.

Comment: @jpa Or a long bastard file?  Or maybe a half round?  You could also apply tape to the side you don't want any action happening on...

Comment: @rrauenza -- I second the file idea.  If you want a manual tool, a file on a stick will hold up much better than sandpaper.

Comment: I don't think a stick (or other long hand tool) would give you enough pressure against the screw tip to do anything.